# Add combobox dynamically with checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a combobox when a checkbox is clicked.

The code I am using is below. As it stands, I can get it to move around a combobox that already exists, but it won't create a new one.

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine the CheckState of the check box.  
        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {  

            combo.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4",
                "item 5",
                "Item 6"});
            combo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 123);
            combo.Name = "combo";
            combo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            combo.TabIndex = 0;
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.combo_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.BringToFront();

            this.AllowDrop = false;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (checkBox1.CheckState)
        {
            case CheckState.Checked:
                ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
                Controls.Add(combo);
                break;
            case CheckState.Unchecked:

                break;
            case CheckState.Indeterminate:

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't see any issues so I threw this code into a new application and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Maybe you mean that it doesn't seem to create more than one control? But, why a CheckBox? If it's unchecked, the Control it created should disappear?

Comment: That's why I am confused. I don't understand why it's not working. This seems straightforward, yet nothing comes of it. I already have a combobox in a different place, but that should not affect this one, should it?

Comment: Yes, but, can you see at least **one** new ComboBox?

Comment: it will if that other combobox is at 50,50 on your form.

Comment: I can see the one that I added with the windows forms GUI. If I comment it out, however, nothing changes. I click the checkbox and nothing happens, either way. I also made sure that the other combobox is not at 50,50

Comment: Since the location is always the same `(50, 50)`, they will be created on top of each other. Create a field `private int _y = 50;` and then create the location with `combo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, _y); _y += 30;`

Comment: But it shouldn't be an issue if I remove the other combobox, right? I did that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So `private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
   if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
   { ...}}`? It still doesn't work.

Comment: my only other suggestion is to start a project, place a checkbox in the upper left corner, double-click it and paste your code above into the event that comes up. Run that and see if it has the same results. This is all I did and it works as expected.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't see any new ComboBox, try also `combo.BringToFront()`. Maybe it ended up behind something else. The `CheckedChanged` event is better suited for this, if you really want to use a CheckBox (it looks like a Button could be better, though). Also, check whether you have actually wired the event handler to the right CheckBox (or that you don't have more than one handler with similar names).

Comment: Just came here to say that Jimi, wondering if the event is wired to the checkbox

Comment: Make sure your program goes to the part where you add the combobox and that you are adding to the correct container

Comment: It's not wired, but it occuring in the checkstate case. Shouldn't that be good enough? 50,50 is in a groupbox. Would that be the cause of this?

Comment: `Controls.Add(combo);` is adding the control to the Form's collection of controls. If you want to add it to another container, your GroupBox in this case, use that reference: `this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(combo);`. You're probably inserting the new control under the GroupBox right now (that's why I suggested to use `BringToFront()`).

Comment: So I added `this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.combo)` to my groupbox and `combo.BringToFront();` to the combobox. Yet it's still not working.

Comment: Is the `checkBox1_Click` Event triggered? If not, the checkbox event is not assigned to the method `checkBox1_Click`. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: What you're saying is not reflected in the code you updated. You're still adding your ComboBox o the Form's collection. But, it should be visible anyway. Have you debugged the event handler's code. Set a breakpoint there and see what happens when (if) the event it's raised.

Comment: So the problem now is that the combobox is there to begin with, instead of only appearing when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve is to be conscious of which function you are placing your statements into. The combobox's settings (the range, location, etc.) will be in the `CheckChanged` function under the `if checked` condition. These will go along with the `groupbox.controls.add();` and `combo.BringToFront();`, just in case it ends up behind something.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine the CheckState of the check box.  
        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(combo);
            combo.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4",
                "Item 5",
                "Item 6"});
            combo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 123);
            combo.Name = "combo";
            combo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            combo.TabIndex = 0;
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.combo_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.BringToFront();

            this.AllowDrop = false;
}
```

Meanwhile, in the `Click` function, you must instantiate the combobox and add it.

```
    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (checkBox1.CheckState)
        {
            case CheckState.Checked:
                ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
                Controls.Add(combo);
                break;
            case CheckState.Unchecked:

                break;
            case CheckState.Indeterminate:

                break;
        }
    }
```

If you then want to get rid of the combobox once the checkbox is unchecked, just add

```
        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            groupBox1.Controls.Remove(combo);
            Controls.Remove(combo);
            combo.Items.Clear();
        }
```

into the `private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` function.
Make sure to put `combo.items.Clear()` or it will add the range of the new instance of the combobox to the old one.